# How to containerize an environment-dependent legacy application writen in Java

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven, tomcat

We have a legacy application written in Java using Apache Struts 1.x and Spring 2.x that we want to containerize.

The problem we have is in the way this project is configured. It is done through Maven properties and profiles (one for each environment) that are turned into properties files. These properties, at compile time, are placed inside the WAR.

What would be the correct way to create an image of this application without modifying the project code? That is, that somehow the configuration is externalized, for example, in environment variables. Maybe it should be in a volume?

So far what we have achieved is a two-stage Dockerfile, where it first compiles with Maven with a specific profile and then copies the WARs in the second stage from a Tomcat image. But doing it this way the generated Docker image is not environment independent, which is what we want to achieve.

Thanks!

Comment: That kind of depends on what is done with that properties file and which `PropertyPlaceHolder` support class is being used. If it is the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` it is pretty easy to do, if it is the old `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` it is possible but harder (requires some configuration). So without knowing how things are being loaded this is hard to tell.

Comment: The configuration is obtained using the ResourceBundle class. Thanks!

Comment: Then there is no solution I'm afraid. The spring stuff can tap into the environment, the resource bundles cannot. I also wonder why that is chosen over the regular approach of the placeholder configurer. Seems like working around the framework rather then working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Config Server provides an HTTP resource-based API for external configuration (name-value pairs or equivalent YAML content). The server is embeddable in a Spring Boot application, by using the @EnableConfigServer annotation.

So will deploy the Spring Cloud config server on one container containing all the environment configurations - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html

Once it's deployed, you can easily deploy your application docker image in different environments using a bootstrap.yml file that accepts the cloud-config server based on the profiles (dev/uat/staging/prod)

```
###
server:
  port: 9092
spring:
  application:
    name: application-name
  cloud:
    config:
      urI: REPLACE_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI (https://<spring_cloud_config_url>:8888/)
  profiles:
    active: REPLACE_PROFILE (dev/uat/staging/prod)
  management:
    endpoints:
      web:
        exposure:
          include: refresh
```